# Getting just email body using mail-listener-2

Tags: node.js, email

I am using [mail-listener-2](https://github.com/simple-designs/mail-listener2) and node.js to receive emails. I have it all setup doing what I want except for one thing.

I can not figure out how to get just the text of the current message. This is what I mean.

```
1. Send an email in my application with a unique id in the subject.

2. User receives email in inbox and replies.

3. Mail-Listener-2 grabs the email reply and saves it under the unique id.
```

Code:

```
mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){

   var body = mail.text

});
```

Now when step 3 occurs, it's grabbing the entire thread message. Instead of just the message the user sent. Meaning, my original message plus the users new message is included in the reply.

Is there a way to grab just the users reply? Or do I just need to do something like putting a line in the message and then parse everything before the line?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){

   text:mail.text

});
```

Comment: `mail.html` may be what's needed for html-based emails